# please help, cant open files/folders after upgrade, emergency

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, nautilus, files, directory

Help me please :(, I recommended to a friend to upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04, but he had no backup of his files.

When the upgrade proccessfinished and he rebooted his laptop, after login, he tried t open a file in his desktop, but none of them opened, the screen just frezed a second and his files were gone for a moment, after that all the file came back, but still without been able to open them.

I check the files from a terminal and only showed some of the files that he had, not all that appears on nautilus. And that files can be opened with no problems.

Please, please help me, he has very important files in his laptop, this an emergency.

Comment: Tried booting into recovery mode and doing an fsck?

Comment: Most probably nautilus or related application crashing. In that base You may access all your files from a live CD

Comment: I was able to recover most of the files with the live CD, some others where lost, but the important files are safe now, I had to reinstall ubuntu 14.04 but now he has a backup. Thanks :D